# OpenCV C++: How to find all the circles in an image

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am trying to find all the circles in the following image and Identify the defect.

this is my code:

```html
static void findCircles2(const Mat& image)
{
 vector<Vec3f> circles;
 int thresh1 = 5;
    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
    pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
 for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
        Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh1, 5);
        //dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
        gray = gray0 >= (1)*255/N;
  gray = gray0 >= (2)*255/N;
  gray = gray0 >= (6)*255/N;
  namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo 1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo 1", gray );
  waitKey(0);

  HoughCircles( gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
  cout<<"size of circles: "<<circles.size()<<endl;
  for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
  {
   Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
   int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
   circle( gray, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
   circle( gray, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
  }

  /// Show your results
  namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo 2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo 2", gray );

   waitKey(0);

    }
}
```

Picture:

[image]

however the code is unable to find anything, I played arround with the thresholds but it doesnt help. please advise.

Development platform: VS2010, Opencv version: 2.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the circles are so small and not that `standard`, so you cann't just do `HoughCircles` on the binary image.

An alternative method is to `findContours`, then filter the contours by ratio between the value of `contourArea` and the value of `minEnclosingCircle`.

---

[image]